# mysql connection error on rails 2.3.14

Tags: mysql, macos

I've been trying to work MySQL on Rails 2.3.14. I've to work with Rails2 but i can't work MySQL.

I've setup MySQL with brew according to http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/ this tutorial but when i tried to run

```
$ mysql
```

i've faced to

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read section 6 on the page you linked to? It talks about your problem.

Comment: Yes I did. However I've faced to the same problem. I don't understan why socket cant see the Cellar/mysql ...

Comment: Have you verified that mysqld is actually running?

Answer (score 0):

All right mates.

I got it.

First I killed all mysql process

```
killall mysqld
```

and then I uninstalled mysql from brew

```
$brew uninstall mysql
$brew cleanup
```

after that I installed mysql again as http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/

so I fixed the problem.